# Infinite recursion detected when updating from function (psycopg2, python 2.7, postgres 9.3)

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS someTable (
    row_id                 smallserial PRIMARY KEY,
    name                   text NOT NULL,
    creation_date          timestamp with time zone DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    last_updated_date      timestamp with time zone DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    created_by             text DEFAULT "current_user"(),
    last_updated_by        text DEFAULT "current_user"()
);
```

with the following rule:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE log_update_some_table AS
    ON UPDATE TO someTable
    DO ALSO 
        UPDATE someTable 
            SET last_updated_date = current_timestamp, 
                last_updated_by = current_user;
```

and a very simple function in plpgsql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_update ()
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE someTable
    SET name = 'test'
    WHERE row_id = 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

One would think the function would run just fine, but I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: infinite recursion detected in rules for relation "sometable"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE someTable
    SET name = 'test'
    WHERE row_id = 1"
PL/pgSQL function test_update() line 3 at SQL statement
```

Why isn't this working and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: So that's the culprit? The goal of the rule was to update the `last_updated_date` and `last_updated_by` fields just once whenever someone updates `someTable`. What do I need to change to prevent it from looping indefinitely? Do I get rid of the `DO ALSO` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your update rule on `someTable` triggers an update on `someTable` which executes the rule which updates `someTable` which executes the rule...

I'd use a simple trigger instead, something like this:

```
create or replace function log_update_some_table() returns trigger as $$
begin
    NEW.last_updated_date = current_timestamp;
    NEW.last_updated_by   = current_user;
    return NEW;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger log_update_some_table_trigger
before update on someTable
for each row execute procedure log_update_some_table();
```

should do the trick. That will modify the row *before* the update happens rather than adding another update (which triggers the recursion problem) to the queue.

Comment: This doesn't work either :( Completely removing the trigger gets rid of the error, but it'd be nice for these fields to be automatically updated.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Works fine for me. Did you drop the rule before adding the trigger?

Comment: Yeah I replaced my rules with your trigger and function. When I tried to update I still got the recursion error, which is odd.

Comment: Are you sure you removed the rule? You're still getting an "infinite recursion detected in rules" error even though you don't have any rules?

Comment: You're right, it did work. I must have not saved my changes before testing. Sorry for the false alarm. Thanks again, you're a lifesaver!